# Similar function to SQL 'WHERE' clause in R

Tags: sql, r

I have a data set assigned to a variable named 'temps', which have columns 'date', 'temperature', 'country'.
I want to do something like this, which I can do in SQL

```
SELECT * FROM temps WHERE country != 'mycountry'
```

How can I do similar selection in R?

Comment: `library(dplyr) ; temps %>% filter(country != 'mycountry')` ... or see [`sqldf`](https://github.com/ggrothendieck/sqldf), if you like

Comment: @alistaire I don't think I want an external library to do the job.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

We can use similar syntax in `base R`

```
temps[temps$country != "mycountry",]
```

#### Benchmarks

```
set.seed(24)
temps1 <- data.frame(country = sample(LETTERS, 1e7, replace=TRUE),
                  val = rnorm(1e7))
system.time(temps1[!temps1$country %in% "A",])
#  user  system elapsed 
#   0.92    0.11    1.04 
system.time(temps1[temps1$country != "A",])
#   user  system elapsed 
#   0.70    0.17    0.88
```

If we are using package solutions

```
library(sqldf)
system.time(sqldf("SELECT * FROM temps1 WHERE country != 'A'"))
#   user  system elapsed 
# 12.78    0.37   13.15 

library(data.table)
system.time(setDT(temps1, key = 'country')[!("A")])
#   user  system elapsed 
#  0.62    0.19    0.37
```

Answer (score 5):

This should do it.

```
temps2 <- temps[!temps$country %in% "mycountry",]
```

Answer (score 3):

Here are sqldf and base R approaches with the source and sample output based on the input shown in the Note below.

**1) sqldf**

```
library(sqldf)
sqldf("SELECT * FROM temps WHERE country != 'mycountry'")
##   country value
## 1   other     2
```

**2) base R**

```
subset(temps, country != "mycountry")
##   country value
## 2   other     2
```

**Note:** The test data used above are shown here. Next time pleaes provide such reproducible sample data in the question.

```
# test data
temps <- data.frame(country = c("mycountry", "other"), value = 1:2)
```